# How to use regexp_replace to replace a character in a string using the select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

Following is my code

```
select (upper(fname)||' '||upper(mname)||' '||upper(lname)) as customer_name,
(indv_corp_flag) as Customer_type,
(regexp_replace(passport_no,'D','B')"regexp_replace") as passport_no, 
(case when indv_corp_flag = 'C' then registration_no else null end) as registration_no,
(case when indv_corp_flag = 'I' then marital_status else null end) as Marital_status
from Nbfc_krishnan_m;
```

it gives error like

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 91 Column: 38
```

But on operating individually it works like

```
select
regexp_replace(passport_no,'S','d')"regexp_replace" 
from nbfc_krishnan_m;
```

is successfully executed.

Comment: You are using two aliases, `regexp_replace` and `passport_no`. Use any one.

Comment: still not working ... just tried it

Comment: it gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrapped all the columns of your projection in unnecessary brackets.  It compiles but the clutter is preventing you from seeing the problem.  Without those brackets it becomes clear you have a column with two aliases:

```
regexp_replace(passport_no,'D','B')"regexp_replace" as passport_no
```

You posted a working query.  It works because it has only one alias.  Hence the solution is obvious:

```
select upper(fname)||' '||upper(mname)||' '||upper(lname) as customer_name,
        indv_corp_flag as Customer_type,
        regexp_replace(passport_no,'D','B') as passport_no, 
        case when indv_corp_flag = 'C' then registration_no else null end as registration_no,
        case when indv_corp_flag = 'I' then marital_status else null end as Marital_status
from Nbfc_krishnan_m;
```

In future reserve brackets for expressions which actually need them.

---

> " if the string is DCCFF12996 and I want output to be BCCFF12669"

You're just substituting one character for another, so you should use the standard [TRANSLATE()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions216.htm#SQLRF06145) function.  Only use REGEXP_REPLACE() when you need a regular expression (i.e. a pattern).

```
SQL> select upper(fname||' '||mname||' '||lname) as customer_name,
  2     passport_no, 
  3     translate(passport_no,'D69','B96') as new_passport_no 
  4  from Nbfc_krishnan_m; 

CUSTOMER_NAME                     PASSPORT_N NEW_PASSPO
--------------------------------- ---------- ----------
FOX IN SOCKS                      ABCD123    ABCB123
DAISY HEAD MAYZIE                 DCCFF12996 BCCFF12669

SQL>
```

Comment: yup , it worked. thanx But, if in the string  in passport_no if I want to replace more than one character so should I use 'and' and write another replace function

Comment: I can't understand your requirement from that.  You need to pass some sample input and desired output.

Comment: okay, if the string is DCCFF12996 and I want output to be BCCFF12669 . then what's your suggestion.